# Convert gpkg to OSM using ogr2ogr

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I tried converting `.osm` file to `.gpkg` file and it works just fine, like this:

```
$ ogr2ogr output2.gpkg somefile.osm
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

but when I reverse it back it won't work.

```
$ ogr2ogr output2.osm output2.gpkg
ERROR 1: Cannot guess driver for output2.osm
```

I also tried

```
$ogr2ogr -f osm output2.osm output2.gpkg
ERROR 1: osm driver does not support data source creation.
```

another attempt is using ogr2osm but this also returned an error from python.

```
$ ogr2osm output2.osm
...

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main                                       return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                            

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code                                                  exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                               

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\Scripts\ogr2osm.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>                               File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ogr2osm\ogr2osm.py", line 271, in main                              osmdata.process(datasource)                                                                                           

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ogr2osm\osm_data.py", line 406, in process                          self.add_feature(ogrfeature, layer_fields, datasource.source_encoding, reproject)                                     

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ogr2osm\osm_data.py", line 354, in add_feature                      osmgeometries = self.__parse_geometry(ogrgeometry, feature_tags)                                                      

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ogr2osm\osm_data.py", line 329, in __parse_geometry                 osmgeometries.append(self.__parse_collection(ogrgeometry, tags))                                                      

File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ogr2osm\osm_data.py", line 297, in __parse_collection               if len(members) == 1 and len(members[0].nodes) <= self.max_points_in_way:    

                                       
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'nodes'
```

I'm stuck. How do I convert the `.gpkg` back to `.osm` using ogr2ogr?

Comment: As `ogr2ogr --formats` notes, `"OSM" (readonly)`, so ogrtools can't create OSMs, sorry.

Comment: @barrycarter oh no. do you happen to know any solution beside ogr2ogr? I need my ```.gpkg``` in ```.osm``` format.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats may or may not be helpful-- OSM may be a family of formats, not a single format?

Answer (score 1):

Try the ogr2osm utility https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm. It should still work even the project is not active at the moment.

> Ogr2osm will read any data source that ogr can read and handle
> reprojection for you. It takes a python file to translate external
> data source tags into OSM tags, allowing you to use complicated logic.
> If no translation is specified it will use an identity translation,
> carrying all tags from the source to the .pbf or .osm output.

Answer (score 1):

Ogr2ogr is not capable of converting to osm, you need to use another tool like for example ogr2osm. It expects at least the input file as parameter, in your case that will be the `.gpkg` file in stead of the `.osm` file, e.g. `ogr2osm output2.gpkg`